# How can I see which monitor correspond to display X in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, external-display

I have 3 monitors connected to my computer running Windows 10:

[image]

[image]

How can I see which monitor correspond to display 1, 2 and 3 in Windows 10? E.g. does display #1 correspond to monitor `2752` or the Asus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*It is not sure if you want to identify the physical monitors or as the in devices list. If you meant the latter, replace the part "display X" with "display X in the devices list".*

This method only works if you can correspond the physical screen to the devices list - e.g by model numbers or disconnecting others and connecting only one.

> ### Identify a display
>
> To see which number corresponds to a display, select `Start  > Settings > System > Display > Rearrange your displays`, then select Identify. A number appears on the screen of the display it's assigned to.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-multiple-monitors-in-windows-329c6962-5a4d-b481-7baa-bec9671f728a#Category=Windows_10

For avoid further confusions try to give names for the monitors - related: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-rename-printer-windows-10.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution, which works in case one doesn't have physical access to the monitors: clicking on `Advanced display settings`:

[image]

It'll display the monitor name for each display:

[image]

Comment: Of course this has limited usefulness when some of the screens use *exactly the same name*, as the two `2752` entries in your example (both question and answer).

Comment: @BenVoigt Unless they're connected to different adapters?

Comment: Hehe, If someone is technically geek for some level they can find a solutions after poking for sometime. cheers!